# elastic search must not with boolean and terms not working

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, boolean, match, n-gram

i am using must , must not in boolean query, and it is working in some case and it is not working in some palce , i don't know the reason

Query :

```
{
                               "from" : "0", "size" : "50",
                               "sort" : [
                                {"post_added_on" : {"order" : "desc"}}
                                ],
                                "query" : {
                                        "bool":{
                                             "must":[
                                               {
                                                "match" : { 
                                                    "post_added_by" : "6870220"
                                                    }
                                               },{
                                                "terms" : { 
                                                    "post_type" :["1","3","5","9","10","11","12","2","4","6","18","23","24","25","8", "14","19","20","21","22"]
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                "terms" : {                     
                                                "post_status" :["1"]
                                                  }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                                    ,
                            "must_not": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "post_id": ["comQues_224","comQues_836","comQues_937","comQues_2793","comQues_2816","comQues_3214","comQues_3753","comQues_3754"]
                                    }
                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

and the result is

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_index] => community_contents
            [_type] => community_contents
            [_id] => comQues_3753
            [_score] => 
            [_source] => Array
                (
                    [post_id] => comQues_3753
                    [community_id] => 0
                    [languages_id] => 24
                    [goal_id] => 0
                    [post_type] => 1
                    [post_source_type] => 1
                    [post_title] => testing create discussion post
                    [reference_id] => 1
                    [post_desc] => testing create discussion post description content
                    [post_status] => 1
                    [post_added_on] => 11
                    [post_updated_on] => 11
                    [post_added_by] => 11
                    [post_file_type] => 1
                    [post_file_name] => 
                    [post_thumbnail_name] => 
                    [sub_details] => []
                )

            [sort] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1668581649
                )

        )
```

Actually this keyword i have added in comQues_3753

It is not working

Comment: please make sure that your query and your response example are both correct and related

Comment: Yeah it is correct only,

Comment: Could you please also share the mapping of your index? And, also, do you get the same result if you're querying elasticsearch directly via curl without using the client?